# How can I retrieve input values from elements added after page load?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, zend-framework

I'm working with Zend Framework 1.12 and I've need to be able to dynamically add and delete fields from a sub-form, in this case we're associating hyperlinks to a parent "promotion".

I haven't found a way to accomplish dynamically adding and removing elements via Zend, and the rare tutorial I've found that claimed to do this are half a decade old and aren't working when I attempt them.

So what I am doing is storing the links I need to work with in a Zend Hidden input field and then dealing with the JSON data after I submit.   Not very efficient, but it's the only thing I've gotten to work so far.

Below is the section of the code I'm working with:

Assume a form like:

```
<form action="/promos/edit/promo_id/15" method="POST" id="form_edit">
   <!-- input is Zend_Form_Element_Hidden -->
   <input type="hidden" id="link_array" value="{ contains the JSON string }"/>

   <button id="add_link">Add Link</button>
</form>
```

The purpose is that every time the Add Link button is pressed, the form adds fields to allow the user to input new hyperlinks that will be associated with the specific items.

Here's the function:

```
// add links
$('#add_link').click(
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        link = '<div class="p_link new_link">' +
                  '<div class="element_wrap">' +
                  '<label for="link_name" class="form_label optional">Text: </label>' +
                  '<input type="text" id="new_link_name" name="link_name"/>' +
                  '</div>' +
                  '<div class="element_wrap">' +
                  '<label for="link_http" class="form_label optional">http://</label>' +
                  '<input type="text" id="new_link_http" name="link_http"/>' +
                  '</div>' +
                  '<div class="element_wrap">' +
                  '<button class="submit delete_link">Delete</button>' +
                  '</div>' +
               '</div>';

        $('#add_link').prev().after(link);
    }
);
```

Now, what I need to do is on submit, for every new_link class element, to take the links name and http reference and place it in a json object.   Here's the code as I have it so far (I know I don't have both input fields represented at this point):

```
$('#submit').click(
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var link_array = [];

        var new_links = document.getElementsByClassName('new_link');
        $.each(new_links, function() {
            console.log(this);
            var n = $(this).children('#new_link_name').text();
            console.log(n);
            link_array.push({'link_name':n}); //'link_http':h
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(link_array));
    }
);
```

My problem is that: `var new_links = document.getElementsByClassName('new_link');` will collect all the newly added new_link elements, but it does not pull in any value that has been input into the text fields.

I need to know how I can apparently bind any input I make to the input field's value attribute, because right now anything I type into these new elements are tossed out and the field appears empty when it's anything but.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#submit').click(
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var link_array = [];

        var new_links = $('.new_link');
        $.each(new_links, function() {
            console.log(this);
            var n = $(this).find('input').val(); // you need input values! This line //is changed...
            console.log(n);
            link_array.push({'link_name':n}); //'link_http':h
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(link_array));
    }
);
```

JSFIDDLE: **http://jsfiddle.net/DZuLJ/**

EDit: You can't have multiple IDS (make class for each input, and target class, if you want link names and http's)

Comment: Hah.   Of course, after two hours of beating my head against a wall, I finally stumbled across a similar solution, using querySelector().value instead.   Regardless, points to you, sir.

Comment: Np, here is updated version - with classes: http://jsfiddle.net/DZuLJ/2/ (generated html is changed, too) and you can easily get value from each input, hopefully.